# How to extract from a list of objects a list of specific attribute?

Tags: python

I have a list of objects. Object has 3 string attributes. I want to make a list containing only a specific attribute from class.

Is there any built-in functions to do that?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

A list comprehension would work just fine:

```
[o.my_attr for o in my_list]
```

But there is a combination of built-in functions, since you ask :-)

```
from operator import attrgetter
map(attrgetter('my_attr'), my_list)
```

Comment: that's not a built-in if you need to import. ;) http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html

Comment: I plead nuance: "built-in" != "__builtins__'. Well, that's my story and I'm sticking to it, officer. :-)

Comment: and how to retrieve 2 (or more) attributes from this class?

Comment: I was looking for `o["myattr"]` which you might infer from the object structure. This is the correct way.

Answer (score 11):

are you looking for something like this?

```
[o.specific_attr for o in objects]
```

Answer (score 10):

The first thing that came to my mind:

```
attrList = map(lambda x: x.attr, objectList)
```

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you want field `b` for the objects in a list named `objects` do this:

```
[o.b for o in objects]
```