# Extract list of attributes from list of objects in python

Tags: list, loops, python

I have an *uniform* list of objects in python:

```py
class myClass(object):
    def __init__(self, attr):
        self.attr = attr
        self.other = None

objs = [myClass (i) for i in range(10)]
```

Now I want to extract a list with some attribute of that class (let's say `attr`), in order to pass it to some function (for plotting that data for example)

What is the pythonic way of doing the following:

```py
attr = [o.attr for o in objs]
```

Maybe derive list and add a method to it, so I can use some idiom like
`objs.getattribute("attr")`?

Comment: See duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/677656/127465, esp. the answer with operator.attrgetter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extract from a list of objects a list of specific attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677656/how-to-extract-from-a-list-of-objects-a-list-of-specific-attribute)

Answer (score 114, accepted):

You can also write:

```
attr=(o.attr for o in objsm)
```

This way you get a generator that conserves memory. For more benefits look at [Generator Expressions](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/).

Comment: would accessing a specific entry result of a O(n) operation?. e.g would accessing index = 100 of attr[100] will result the generator to run 100 steps?

Answer (score 134):

`attrs = [o.attr for o in objs]` was the right code for making a list like the one you describe. Don't try to subclass `list` for this. Is there something you did not like about that snippet?

Comment: I wonder what is "better" from both answers.With round brackets `()` or with square brackets `[]`. ... The rest of the code is equal. Well, I understand that these are different ways of how it works internally. But as a Python newcomer I don't know if it doesn't matter, which way I should follow.

Comment: @Beauty they do slightly different things, which might matter sometimes, for instance if you wanted to iterate over the result twice or reverse the result.

Answer (score 2):

Another way could be to map `getattr()` on `objs` list.

```py
# for a generator
from itertools import repeat
attrs = map(getattr, objs, repeat('attr'))
# or even without itertools
attrs = map(getattr, objs, ['attr']*len(objs))

# for a list
attrs = list(map(getattr, objs, repeat('attr')))
```

A nice thing about `getattr` is that a default value can be returned if no such attribute exist. For example, the below line returns `'NA'` if `attr` is not defined in an object.

```py
attrs = [getattr(o, 'attr', 'NA') for o in objs]
```

If multiple attributes need to be fetched, `operator.attrgetter` could be useful.

```py
from operator import attrgetter
attrs = list(map(attrgetter('attr', 'other'), objs))
```

N.B. `itertools` and `operator` are in the standard library.