# Extract (not known beforehand) attributes from objects in a list

Tags: python, list, class

I have a class whose attributes are not known beforehand:

```
class Event():
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, key, value)
```

and another one which is basically a list of objects Event:

```
class Collection(list):
    def __init__(self):
        self.members = []

    def add(self,new):
        try:
            self.members.extend(new)
        except TypeError:
            self.members.append(new)
```

Let's say now that I define 3 objects Event:

```
a = Event(name="a",value=1)
b = Event(name="b",value=2)
c = Event(name="c",other=True)
```

And I create a Collection from them:

```
col = Collection()
col.add([a,b,c])
```

What I want is to be able to print out all the values of the objects in the list for a given attribute (if the attribute does not exist for an object, it should return None or any other pre-defined value). For example:

```
print col.name #should return ["a","b","c"]
print col.value #should return [1,2,None]
```

I have read the following answer: [Extract list of attributes from list of objects in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739800/extract-list-of-attributes-from-list-of-objects-in-python)

But that doesn't work here since the name of my attribute is not known by advance, and some might not even be defined. How should I define my class Collection(), or maybe even re-think everything to achieve my goal ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just override the `__getattr__` method of the Collection class, which is called when an attribute is accessed. In order to access to unknown set of attributes you can use `event.__dict__`. So, a possible solution is like this:

```
def __getattr__(self, name):
    return [m.__dict__.get(name) for m in self.members]
```

Comment: `__getattr__` is only called if the normal lookup fails. You don't need the `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

This is a variation of "I want to create dynamic variable names". The solution here is the same: use a dictionary.

```
class Event(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.attributes = dict(kwargs)
```

Your `Collection` class will need a custom `__getattr__` method, so that it can look up values in its `Event` list instead.

```
class Collection(object):
    # assume self.events is a list of Event objects
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return [event.attributes.get(name) for event in self.events]
```

You *could* stick with your current implementation of `Event`, and have `Collection` look at `event.__dict__` instead of `event.attributes`. I don't recall, though, if `__dict__` might contain anything else besides the attributes you explicitly set. I'd err on the side of caution.