# Is it the best way to create an array from a list of objects?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.9

I have a list of objects stored in `socialmedias` variable. One parameter of SocialMedia class is called `username`. I want to create an array with all usernames from that list of objects `socialmedias` and I want to be sure I use the best way.

```
socialmedias = [obj1, obj2, obj3, ..., objN]
usernames = []

for sm in socialmedias:
    usernames.append(sm.username)
print(usernames)
>> [username1, username2, username3, ..., usernameN]
```

Is there any other way to do it in less line of codes I used above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes there is, you can use list comprehension like:

`usernames = [sm.username for sm in socialmedias]`

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
usernames = [sm.username for sm in socialmedias]
```

From: [Extract list of attributes from list of objects in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739800/extract-list-of-attributes-from-list-of-objects-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

By memory I would say by using list comprehension:

```
socialmedias = [obj1, obj2, obj3, ..., objN]
usernames = [sm.username for sm in socialmedias]

print(usernames)
```

It should do the work.

Answer (score 0):

Using a function.

```py
list(map(lambda sm: sm.username, socialmedias))
```